# edit text with accent issue

Tags: android

I'm writing an android application and I have issue with edit text. 
When the user adds text with accent (sp: "Nous sommes en été");
The string isn't correct. It convert my accent symbole to utf-8 I guess. 
How can I deal with it ?

ps: my application is a french app and I really need to use accent.

MY CODE :

```
String description = ((EditText) findViewById(id.description)).getText().toString();
                Log.i("UTF8",description.toString());
                description = description.replace("\n", "");
                Log.i("UTF8",description.toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be a problem. String representations are UTF-16 [1] in java / android. I tried the following code on android and got it to work fine. The accented é displays correctly.

```
EditText findViewById =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.test_text);
findViewById.setText("École. Nous sommes en été");
Editable text = findViewById.getText();
Log.d(TAG, text.toString());
```

You know that the first parameter in your Log.i() code is a tag right ? Log.i() does not accept encoding type as a parameter. Can you post what those statements print ?

[1] - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html