# How to fix vowel accent issue

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I must show a text in an EditText area in Android.

All works fine, but if the text uses vowel chars that have accent,

for example :

`"è", "ì", "à", "ò" "ù"`,

a code is shown, not the right character.

I simply use

```
 String   text= myEditText.getText().toString();
```

to get the String, I store the string in a file and use

```
myEditText.setText(text);
```

to set the String text in the EditText area when I retrieve the data in a second moment.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Aye ok thought you might be doing something else.

Comment: Have you had a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884568/edit-text-with-accent-issue

Comment: There aren't accepted answer in that question and the only code written has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is during saving data to the file. If your file doesn't take a utf8 character set when you save your data, then you read it back without those characters. Therefore make sure you save it correctly:

```
String filePath = "/sdcard/utf8_file.txt";
String UTF8 = "utf8";
int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), UTF8),BUFFER_SIZE);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filePath), UTF8),BUFFER_SIZE);
```

When you read it back, then you should be able to use setText() on your myEditText as you do now.

Comment: Yes the problem is during the saving. However The Strings are nested in a custom Object and I don't know how exactly fix the issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990041/fileoutputstream-cause-string-char-issue

Comment: I think you won't be able to serialize a Java custom object into a String using utf-8 encoding. Better idea would be to store your object in a database as a blob.